# Stop propagation on delegated events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DataTables setup on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9hhaofky/6/). I want the hyperlinks to *not* highlight the row. I use this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    select: {
      style: 'multi'
    }
  });

  $('#example').on('click', 'a.do-nothing', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  });
});
```

I can't seem to fix just that. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Stop propagation is typically an anti-pattern. Delegates can't stop propagation because they're happening *after* the event has already propagated. Toggle state instead of attempting to stop events from propagating.

Answer (score 1):

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6r0zusp/).

```
  $('#example a.do-nothing').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  });
```

According to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data):

Returning `false` from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`. A `false` value can also be passed for the handler as a shorthand for `function(){ return false; }`. So, `$( "a.disabled" ).on( "click", false );` attaches an event handler to all links with class `disabled` that prevents them from being followed when they are clicked and also stops the event from bubbling.

So you might get away with simply: `$('#example a.do-nothing').on('click', false);` if you do not need any other handlers executed on the `a.do-nothing`.

It is curious why your selector filter was not working: if we are using the filter, this works:

`$('#example td').on('click', '.do-nothing', false);`

The following will allow you to continue the click event without bubbling that click up the DOM and triggering the hover:

```
  $('#example td').on('click', '.do-nothing', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! However in my own version i'm using ajax to load the rows so I can't get away with `$('#example a.do-nothing').on('click', function(){});`. Is there any way to still do it?

Comment: See updated answer, if this doesn't work could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with most terms. English is not my native language. This table is just an example. With my actual table all the rows are inserted through ajax. So `#example` is the first parent that is always there, which jQuery can watch. If you go the site in this url you have an example: http://bob.me.tz/jhs97sdf23jh.txt. Clicking the watch icon should not change the row selection. edit: txt file updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just override the CSS? See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbphspmt/1/).

This way you can don't need to mess with javascript.

```
table.dataTable.stripe tbody > tr.odd.selected, table.dataTable.stripe tbody > tr.odd > .selected, 
table.dataTable.display tbody > tr.odd.selected, table.dataTable.display tbody > tr.odd > .selected {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

table.dataTable.hover tbody > tr.selected:hover, table.dataTable.hover tbody > tr > .selected:hover, 
table.dataTable.display tbody > tr.selected:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody > tr > .selected:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

table.dataTable tbody>tr.selected, table.dataTable tbody>tr>.selected {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
```